# I have a slantfin hot water furnace ,it goes on then shuts off every 2 min until. It reaches the set temp

Tags: furnace

Slantfin furnace goes on and off every 2 min until it reaches set temp

Comment: Please include more information, such as the product number and any troubleshooting steps you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious possible issues are:
-- your circulator pump isn't working (and the heat can't get out of the furnace)
-- Your aquastat in the furnace is set too low -- this would cause the furnace to fire until it reached the water temperature listed, but the house would still be calling for more heat.